# How to find duplicates and preserve the later entry

Tags: c#, list, linq, duplicates, compare

I have two lists of objects from different sources that look like this:

```
public class PersonToolDto {
   public int PersonId { get; set; }

   public int ToolId { get; set; }

   public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

var personToolListFromSomeSource = new List<PersonToolDto>{
     new PersonTool{1, 1, 2021-07-07},
     new PersonTool{2, 1, 2021-07-07},
     new PersonTool{3, 1, 2021-07-07},
}

var personToolListFromAnotherSource = new List<PersonToolDto>{
     new PersonTool{1, 1, 2021-06-07},
     new PersonTool{2, 1, 2021-07-07},
     new PersonTool{3, 1, 2021-07-07},
}
```

I want to eradicate the duplicates and only keep the newest entries. What is a simple and fast way with linq or something else to achieve this? A simple groupby by id of a person does not eradicate duplicates and i am a little bit lost how to compare the dates.

I want to keep the structure and continue with a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```cs
var withoutDuplicates = personToolListFromSomeSource
    .Concat(personToolListFromAnotherSource)
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.PersonId, p.ToolId })
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt).First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You can also use the `GroupBy` overload to eliminate the select: `.GroupBy(p => new { p.PersonId, p.ToolId }, (k,v)=>v.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt).First())`

Comment: Also, looks like OP only want distinct by PersonId, not PersonId and ToolId

Answer (score 2):

For the upcoming .NET 6, you can also use the new `DistinctBy`:

```
var output = personToolListFromSomeSource
    .Concat(personToolListFromAnotherSource)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
    .DistinctBy(x => x.PersonId)
    .ToList();
```

.NET 6 also have a `MaxBy`, so another option is:

```
var output = personToolListFromSomeSource
    .Concat(personToolListFromAnotherSource)
    .GroupBy(x => x.PersonId, (k,v) => v.MaxBy(x => x.CreatedAt))    
    .ToList();
```